# Ignoring commas in string literals while reading in .csv file without using any outside libraries

Tags: python, csv, split

I am trying to read in a `.csv` file that has a line that looks something like this:

`"Red","Apple, Tomato"`.

I want to read that line into a dictionary, using "Red" as the key and "Apple, Tomato" as the definition. I also want to do this without using any libraries or modules that need to be imported.

The issue I am facing is that it is trying to split that line into 3 separate pieces because there is a comma between "Apple" and "Tomato" that the code is splitting on. This is what I have right now:

```
file_folder = sys.argv[1]
file_path = open(file_folder+ "/food_colors.csv", "r")

food_dict = {}
for line in file_path:
    (color, description) = line.rstrip().split(',')
    print(f"{color}, {description}")
```

But this gives me an error because it has 3 pieces of data, but I am only giving it 2 variables to store the info in. How can I make this ignore the comma inside the string literal?

Comment: _I also want to do this without using any libraries or modules that need to be imported._ Why? You can always write your own CSV parser, but unless it's for fun/educational purposes, I don't see the point.

Comment: You can collect the remaining split strings in a list by using something like `color, *description = line.rstrip().split(',')`. Note the asterisk before `description`, which makes it into a list. See example [here](https://ideone.com/lxEcB8).

Comment: @AMC This is an assignment for school and that is one of the restrictions

Comment: @BrentMB Ah, a homework question. You're going to need to be more specific, then, we can't do your assignment for you. Relevant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions.

Comment: I suppose you can't use a regular expression instead either?

Comment: One sample is not good enough for a generalized solution. Do you also have lines where you have no commas, or more than one, in the second half?

Comment: @usr2564301 The cases where there are no commas in the string literal work just fine with the code I have in the question. There are no cases where there are more than 1 comma inside the string literal

Comment: @PaulRooney That is a good way to solve this issue. I could then just append the strings in the list to convert it from a list back to string. Thanks!

Comment: The `.split()` method takes an optional second parameter to limit the number of splits - passing `1` would cause it to leave that second comma alone.  This doesn't help if there's any possibility of a comma in the key (rather than the value)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect the remaining strings into a list, like so

```
color, *description = line.rstrip().split(',')
```

You can then join the description strings back together to make the value for your dict

Another way

```
color, description = line.rstrip().split(',', 1)
```

Would mean you only perform the split operation once and the rest of the string remains unsplit.

Comment: Both solutions you have provided are useful. The first allowing for 'n' number of commas to be present in the string literal, and the second allowing for just 1. The latter is most help for my use-case, but both answers are great! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas` package and use `pandas.DataFrame.read_csv`.

For example, this works:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

TESTDATA = StringIO('"Red","Apple, Tomato"')

df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep=",", header=None)

print(df)
```

Comment: I am trying to do this without any external packages

Comment: @BrentMB: you told so in a comment. It would be better if you had added that into your question right from the start (including valid reasons to do so, just in case someone asks the Unavoidable Followup Question...).

Comment: @usr2564301 It's in the title and in the question body. Was it not there from the start?

Comment: @BrentMB I see. My apology for that. Still hope this may be helpful! Cheers!